# why does adding a list element to <body> add extra padding to <html>? CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to set the height of the `body` element to 100% of the viewport.

using this it worked:

#### CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

But then I added a unordered list into the `body`, and now there appears to be about `1em` of extra padding on the top of the html element.

**HTML:** *(Without all of the unrelated elements and attributes)*

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>list item 1</li>
            <li>list item 2</li>
            <li>list item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

This also happens with an ordered list too.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxWau/1/)

*PS: I have only tested this in Firefox and Chrome.*

Comment: Browsers have a default styling for elements. You may want to take a look at http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This margin is added by the `<ul>`.  Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
ul { margin-top: 0px; }
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxWau/3/)

I'm not sure *why* the `<ul>` has a default top margin, nor do I know which browsers do this or if it's per spec, but I think it's safe to say that if you *do not* want a top margin, the safest bet is to always set it explicitly and not worry about what browsers do by default.

Comment: Ah, I almost guessed that, but because of the red background color showing from the `html` element I thought it must be something else. Why does the `ul` element add margin before the `body` element? (Such that the background color of the `html` element shows through.)

Comment: That's anyone's guess!  Probably, because if you have a paragraph of text and then you put in a list, you'd usually want a bit of separation before the list starts.  Otherwise, the first item of the list would jam up against the bottom of your text and look ugly.  However, I don't know if this *default* margin is part of the HTML standard or just something browsers do.

Comment: Actually the [default HTML4 stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) claims `UL` should *have no* top margin.  Weird..

Comment: I recommend `*{margin:0; padding:0}` at the top of the stylesheet, and if an element needs margin/padding, add it manually.

Comment: The weird thing is that it doesn't do it if <body> has a border... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxWau/5/)

Comment: @Stephen: That border thing has to do with [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). If `body` has a border it blocks the `ul` margin from collapsing with it, preventing the "padding" effect.